# Comparing large list of hashes to other large list of hashes

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a list of 100,000 hashes (list a) that I'd like to compare to a list of 15,000,000 hashes (list b).

The hash is taken from list a. If it exists in list b, do nothing. If it does not exist in list b, write it to a file.

Here is the logic I have so far:

```
def compareHashes(map, hashdb, out):
    output_file = openFile(out)
    line_cnt = 0
    total_lines = len(map)
    for m in map:
        if m not in hashdb:
            writeToFile(m + "\r\n", output_file)
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(round(percentage(line_cnt, total_lines), 2)) + "%")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        line_cnt = line_cnt + 1
    output_file.close()
```

It works, but takes an extremely long time. Can I get some suggestions on how to increase the performance on this? The box running the script has 60gb of ram and 8 cores. I dont think all the cores are being utilized because python is not multithreading. Any ideas how I could increase the throughput on this?

Comment: Your code example writes to file if the m is an element of hashdb, which contradicts your statement in paragraph 2.  Please correct your question or code to be in agreement.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my code and question.

Comment: What type is `hashdb`? If it's a `set` rather than a `list`, your code would be fairly efficient.

Comment: hashdb is actually a list of md5 hashes. it is about 15 million hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you state that you'd like to write to file if an element in list a doesn't exist in list b.  This can be represented in code as:

```
for a in list_a:
   if a not in list_b:
       writeFile(...)
```

Using the infix operator **in** on a **list** is an O(n) complexity computation.  Instead, use a **set**, an associative (unordered) array with item lookup in O(1) time.

```
set_b = set(list_b)
for a in list_a:
    if a not in set_b:
         writeFile(...)
```

You can also find all the items in `list_a` that aren't in `list_b` and then only perform actions on those items:

```
a_disjoint_b = set(list_a) - set(list_b)
for a in list_a:
    if a in a_disjoint_b:
        writeFile(...)
```

Or, if the order of items in `list_a` doesn't matter, and all items in `list_a` are unique:

```
for a in set(list_a) - set(list_b):
    writeFile(...)
```

Comment: I used the 2nd solution. The script processed all 100,000 lines against all 15,000,000 lines in roughly 10 seconds, versus the estimated 36 hours from an unsorted list. Thank you very much.

Comment: Using `set(list_a).difference(list_b)` might be more efficient than making an actual set of `list_b` and using the `-` operator. The big-O complexity is the same, but you might avoid some memory allocation overhead that would come from making a big set.

Comment: Good point.  I looked at the Python source (Objects/setobject.c), and if the parameter `list_b` passed to `difference` isn't a **set**, then it makes a copy of `set_a`, and calls `difference_update` which iterates over `list_b`.  So, the most efficient would be `set_a = set(list_a); set_a.difference_update(list_b)`

Comment: After running some tests, using `difference_update` is about 10% faster than `difference`, which is much faster (2.4x) than `set(a) - set(b)`